# Setting up an Application with Azure for use with Graph API outlook calendars

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm aware that Graph API has a nice nuget package and I am confident on the code side of things, but my understanding is that I need to have the application set up in Azure and while there is a lot of documentation about this in general, I find it quite dense and I'm not confident I have the specifics down for how I need to set this portion up.

What I need my application to do is access an outlook calendar of a specific user that I own, read, search, add, delete and update calendar items.  The integration assistant seems to suggest I need to configure a URI redirect and configure api permission.  The default persmission is User.Read on graph API and if I try to add a permission, office 365 management seems like it might be the one I need except it specifically says just retrieving user information and nothing mentions outlook anywhere.

I need to know more or less the minimum steps in setting up the application in Azure to write a C# application that can make changes to outlook for a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`need my application to do is access an outlook calendar of a specific user`

Does it mean you need your app to have the abiltity to modify the callendar of any user you owned? If not, then it means you need your application to provide a sign in module and let users sign in, then the users can get authentication to call graph api and manage their own calendar, since this scenario, users give the delegate api permission, so they can't manage other users' calendar, so I don't think this is what you want.

If so, then you should use `client credential flow` to generate access token to call graph api. I think you know that when you want to call graph api, **you have to get an access token which has correct permission** first.

Ok, then let's come to the api permission, when you go to [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0) of the Calendar. You will see permissions like screenshot below:

[image]

`Application` permission type is suitable for `client credential flow`. And after viewing all the apis, you will find that they all need `Calendars.ReadWrite` except those not supporting `Application` type.

Then let's go to azure portal and reach Azure Active Directory. You need to create an Azure ad application and give the app `Calendars.ReadWrite` permission, then [give the Admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#admin-consent-button).

Then you also need to create a client secret, pls go to `Certificates & Secrets` and add a new client secret, don't forget to copy the secret after you create it.

Now you've done all the steps. No need to set a redirect url, because you don't need to let the user to sign in your application. Let's see [client credential flow document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret), it only require `client_id, client_secret` to generate access token.
Or in the code, you may use SDK like this :

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
    var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
    var clientSecret = "client_secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    var calendar = new Calendar{ Name = "Volunteer" };
    var events = await graphClient.Users["user_id_which_is_needed_to_list_calendar_events"].Events.Request()
                .Header("Prefer","outlook.timezone=\"Pacific Standard Time\"")
                .Select("subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location")
                .GetAsync();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of NoPermissionsInAccessToken
Is that from something I failed to configure in Azure?

Comment: this may be a delay, here's a simiar question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/757812/code-nopermissionsinaccesstoken-message-the-token.html